# Tree View In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hai All
How can i add a tree view in MVC.

Comment: Dyna Tree http://guyellisrocks.com/coding/asp-net-mvc-with-jquery-dynatree-plugin-for-checkboxes/
Telerik Treeview for asp.net mvc
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview

Answer (score 2):

[One example](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/11/25/hierarchical-treeview-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery.aspx) which has been around a while.

[This example](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2009/02/08/asp.net-mvc-recursive-treeview-helper.aspx) is quite descriptive and adds an extension to HtmlHelper of type TreeView.  For example:

```
<%= Html.TreeView("locations",
    Model.Locations,
    l => l.ChildrenLocations,
    l => l.Name) %>
```